# Can't find AddHeadersFilter in CMS Magnolia 5.7.4

Tags: magnolia

I can't find AddHeadersFilter in CMS Magnolia 5.7.4
This class in classpath

```
magnolia-core\5.7.4\magnolia-core-5.7.4.jar!\info\magnolia\cms\filters\AddHeadersFilter.class
```

but not accessible in Magnoia's Configuration panel.

According [documentation](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS56/Filters#Filters-AddingHTTPheaders) it should be there

Any clue how to get access to this filter and configure to support CORS?

Update:
[image]

Update 2: 
Here is how I send request

```
let url = 'http://localhost:8080/en/consumer'
fetch(url, {
   mode: 'no-cors',
   headers: {
       'Content-Type': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3'//,
       //'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*',
   },
  method: "GET"
})
    .then(response => {
        response.text()
        })
    .then(data => {
        frame.innerHTML = data
        })
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not accessible in Magnoia's Configuration panel"? You need to add the filter to filter chain yourself by creating configuration described in documentation. Or did you have issues loading the class from classpath after you created said configuration?

Comment: @Jan Good catch, I thought that the filter should be in the filter chain by default. Will it work only in "public" instance?

Comment: @Jan Filter registered, I can see it in the configuration panel on public instance, but on request debugger not stopping in doFilter method and in browser I still reseive "401 (Unauthorized)" response

Comment: Can you attach screenshot of where exactly in filter chain did you configure it and how your configuration looks like? Thx

Comment: at the very bottom of the chain after uriSecurity

Comment: updated post with snapshot

Comment: That’s wrong. It needs to go higher up. Move it up just after context filter. Filters are executed in the order in which they are defined. Having it at the end means that security filter will kick out request before headers can be added.

Comment: @Jan After move filter up in chain I hit breakpoint inside! Thank you. But response still "index.html:50 GET http://localhost:8080/en/consumer 401 (Unauthorized)"

Comment: @Jan I've added code snippet to post

Comment: if you haven't solved it yet - I might have been advising you wrong. Please place `AddHeadersFilter` right between `uriSecurity` and `range` filters. Hopefully that would take care of the authentication. If not, your problem might be that you are testing it on author instance which requires authentication for all content? If that is the case, you can change anonymous role temporarily to allow all access (`security:web access:get:.*`)

Comment: @Jan. Yes, I realize that testing in Author instance isn't a good idea and start working on building a local Public instance. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

So in summary of the comments above:

- `AddHeadersFilter`filter is not installed OOTB, you have to add it to the filter chain yourself
- when adding `AddHeadersFilter` to the filter chain, make sure you position it between `uriSecurity` and `range` filter
- to avoid issues with authentication, make sure you do testing on local public instance or if you need to test this on author instance, make sure the page you are loading is allowed for anonymous user (on author instance, by default, all pages are denied)