# How to render images from Magnolia CMS on Salesforce Community?

Tags: salesforce, content-management-system, magnolia

I was able to render Text contents from  Magnolia [public REST API](https://demopublic.magnolia-cms.com/.rest/delivery/tours/v1) on Salesforce community.

ISSUE: Image files are being blocked by CSP (Content Security Policy)
[image: jcr error]

[image]

TRIED: Added the Base URL a few different ways to in Site URL in CSP Trusted Sites

```
    https://*.magnolia-cms.com
    https://*.demopublic.magnolia-cms.com
    https://demopublic.magnolia-cms.com

   Also, included https://demopublic.magnolia-cms.com url in Trusted Sites for Script
```

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a typical case of forgetting setting the CORS headers on Magnolia site, hence browser blocking the request as required by the spec:

> For security reasons, browsers restrict cross-origin HTTP requests initiated from scripts. For example, XMLHttpRequest and the Fetch API follow the same-origin policy. This means that a web application using those APIs can only request resources from the same origin the application was loaded from unless the response from other origins includes the right CORS headers.

[More details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

If you haven't done so before, you can add simple static CORS definition in headers using `AddHeadersFilter`. It was discussed previously eg [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58528045/cant-find-addheadersfilter-in-cms-magnolia-5-7-4)

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for taking your time for answering. I am using Public API from Magnolia (https://demopublic.magnolia-cms.com/.rest/delivery/tours/v1), so I assume they already enabled CORS in their side. 

I white listed https://demopublic.magnolia-cms.com base url in Salesforce CORS, but still having a CORS issue.

Comment: You got it the other way around. It is necessary for Magnolia to allow salesforce so that response coming from Magnolia list salesforce as origin otherwise browser is required to block the request for data from Magnolia. To test it, I suggest you execute against your local Magnolia instance. Demo is reset regularly so any settings you make them will be wiped out in few minutes.